# create cookie in asmx web service and retrive it in java script function

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, web-services

I am using a web service in ASP.NET page, but I am unable to create cookie in web service. After creating a cookie I want to retrieve its value in my on JavaScript function.

Example:

```
HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("doc1count");
cookie.Value = "my values nitesh";
HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Add(Cookie);
```

But this code is not working in asmx web service

Also I want to retrieve its value on my ASP.NET page in JavaScript, if this task is not possible using cookies, then how do I do that with session?

Comment: Look this: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15519454/how-can-i-access-session-variables-and-set-them-in-javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15519454/how-can-i-access-session-variables-and-set-them-in-javascript) [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3297637/getting-session-in-net-asmx-web-service](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3297637/getting-session-in-net-asmx-web-service)

Comment: but i am unable to create session in asmx web service, shows me the error the the name 'Session' does not exists in the current context, i have also tried   [WebMethod(EnableSession = true)] but its not working

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6969563/session-does-not-exist-in-the-current-context](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6969563/session-does-not-exist-in-the-current-context)