# how to use session in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, session

I am creating a web app in which i want to store userid and role in `session` through `Angularjs`

this is my Angularjs file

```
$http.get('/login.asmx/loginuser', {
                params: {
                    log: $scope.log,
                    pm: $scope.pm,
                    password: $scope.password
                }
            })
            .then(function (response) {
                {
                    $scope.suc = response.data;
                    console.log(response.data);
                    if (response.data == 'success') {
                        console.log('success');
                        $window.location.href = "../welcomepage/welcometable";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        console.log('nosuccess');
                        $window.location.href = "../Login/Index";
                    }
                }
            })
```

i need to store `$scope.pm` and `$scope.log` in my session and want to use the same on my welcome page

how to store and use sessions in angularjs?

Comment: i think, the best way to use localStorage module! Or Otherwise you can go for https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies/service/$cookieStore

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10629617/4689622

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use session storage or local storage for that, here is the example of session storage.

> session storage or local storage will not work here in stack overflow
>   so refer given link.

[Link](http://codepen.io/chrisenytc/pen/gyGcx)

```js
window.addCart = function($scope, $http, $window, $document){
  
    var getValue = function(){
        return $window.sessionStorage.length;
    }
      
    var getData = function(){
      var json = [];
      $.each($window.sessionStorage, function(i, v){
        json.push(angular.fromJson(v));
      });
      return json;
    }
      
    $scope.images = getData();
    $scope.count = getValue();
  
    $scope.addItem = function(id){
        var image = document.getElementById('img'+id);
        json = {
          id: id,
          img: image.src
        }
        $window.sessionStorage.setItem(id, JSON.stringify(json));
        $scope.count = getValue();
        $scope.images = getData();
    }
    
    $scope.removeItem = function(id){
      $window.sessionStorage.removeItem(id);
      $document.
      $scope.count = getValue();
      $scope.images = getData();
      alert('Removed with Success!');
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.21/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="">
    <div ng-controller="addCart">
      <p>{{ count }}</p>
      <div>
        <img id="img16" src="http://placehold.it/351x350"/>
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" ng-click="addItem('16')">Add to Cart</a>
      </div>
      <div>
        <img id="img5" src="http://placehold.it/352x350"/>
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" ng-click="addItem('5')">Add to Cart</a>
      </div>
      <div>
        <img id="img32" src="http://placehold.it/353x350"/>
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" ng-click="addItem('32')">Add to Cart</a>
      </div>
      <div>
        <img id="img43" src="http://placehold.it/354x350"/>
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" ng-click="addItem('43')">Add to Cart</a>
      </div>
      <hr />
      <table>
        <thead>
          <td>Image</td>
          <td>Options</td>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr ng-repeat="data in images" id>
            <td><img ng-src="{{ data.img }}"/></td>
            <td><a href="javascript:void(0)" ng-click="removeItem(data.id)">Remove Item {{ data.id }}</a>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 angular.module('cookieStoreExample', ['ngCookies'])
  .controller('ExampleController', ['$cookieStore', function($cookieStore) {
     // Put cookie
  $cookieStore.put('myFavorite','oatmeal');
  // Get cookie
  var favoriteCookie = $cookieStore.get('myFavorite');
  // Removing a cookie
  $cookieStore.remove('myFavorite');
}]);
```

[look on](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies/service/$cookieStore)